# Zoom option error on gdal_tiler.py

Tags: python, gdal, tiles, zoom

I'm using the tiler-tools library from: https://code.google.com/p/tilers-tools/wiki/QuickStart

And specifically this command: `./gdal_tiler.py --zoom=9-15 my_map.vrt`

To generate tiles. When I use the --zoom option, I get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '9-15'
```

From this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./gdal_tiler.py", line 184, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "./gdal_tiler.py", line 177, in main
    parallel_map(process_src, flatten(res))
  File "/usr/share/nginx/www/newtest/tilers_tools/tiler_functions.py", line 97, in parallel_map
    return map(func, iterable)
  File "./gdal_tiler.py", line 66, in process_src
    prm.walk_pyramid()
  File "/usr/share/nginx/www/newtest/tilers_tools/tiler_backend.py", line 662, in walk_pyramid
    if not self.init_map(self.options.zoom):
  File "/usr/share/nginx/www/newtest/tilers_tools/tiler_backend.py", line 271, in init_map
    self.calc_zoom(zoom_parm)
  File "/usr/share/nginx/www/newtest/tilers_tools/tiler_backend.py", line 490, in calc_zoom
    self.set_zoom_range(zoom_parm, (min_zoom, max_zoom))
  File "/usr/share/nginx/www/newtest/tilers_tools/tiler_backend.py", line 990, in set_zoom_range
    zlist.append(int(zchunk[0]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '9-15'
```

After that error the command drops and tiles aren't generated – what's wrong?

Comment: It looks like it wants a single number instead of a range. The documentation says it can handle it but I'm thinking that part is broken. The code prior to that line is zchunk_lst = [z.split(':') for z in zoom_parm.split(',')] which is looking for commas or colons, perhaps try a colon instead:  gdal_tiler.py --zoom=9:15 my_map.vrt and if that gives no joy gdal_tiler.py --zoom=9,10,11,12,13,14,15 my_map.vrt

Answer (score 2):

The documentation appears to be incorrect.  Try using a colon instead of a dash, as in:

```
--zoom=9:15
```